# Event manager extension

Tags: extensions, event-observer

I am looking for a free event(like exhibitions) manager extension that can list events in a list instead of a full calendar.
I need to be able to output like:

```
2013 events
August 10th
This is a new event
August 12th
This is a new event

2014 events
August 10th
This is a new event
August 12th
This is a new event
```

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Type them into a cms page? :)

Comment: That was also my first idea. But the problem is that the customer is not code strong, so it need to be simple. Like a plugin with textboxes and dates :)

Comment: Write extension to manage events.

Comment: Read my post ;)

Comment: you may use ready made module http://store.webkul.com/Magento-Event-Manger.html

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at our event manager extension which provide a extensive tool to manage all your event.

http://ecommage.com/blog/magento-event-management-extension/

Feel free to get back to me if you have any feedback.

Comment: Is there a way in your extension to display the events as requested in the opening post? Plus your extension is not free.